# Extracting a folder name using Regex

Tags: python, regex

The folders (\one \two \three \four) could be named anything.

What I do know is that \KNOWN will always appear in the folders I'm looking at.  What I want to do is find a way to extract the name of \three.  You can see my attempt below, but this only extracts \four.  Thanks!

```
my_directory = r'e:\\one\\two\\three\\four\\KNOWN\\data'
myFolder = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z_]+)\\KNOWN', my_directory).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you `three` by requiring there be some non-`\` characters (`[^\\]`) between the group and the `KNOWN`:

```
my_directory = r'e:\\one\\two\\three\\four\\KNOWN\\data'
myFolder = re.search(r'([a-zA-Z_]+)\\[^\\]+\\KNOWN', my_directory).group(1)
```

*(not entirely sure the `\` in the `[^...]` part should be escaped in Python but I'm pretty sure it should)*

Comment: You're welcome, please accept an answer when the time lets you. That way we both get some points and it helps the site :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex :

```
([a-zA-Z]+)(?=\\([a-zA-Z_]+)\\KNOWN)
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3arql).

It uses lookaheads to check for \folder\KNOWN.

Comment: Please accept the answer that suits you to close the question, @SuperDougDougy ! Have a good day :-)